# User created in SQLPlus cannot be connected with SQL Developer

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I created a user in SQLPlus and granted all privileges to it. I can connect this user in SQLPlus but cannot connect in SQL Developer. I can connect hr and system in SQL Developer but not this user. It shows this error -> Status : Failure -Test failed: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied.
I have checked the username, password and it is correct.
I have checked the tnsnames.ora file and the SID and Port No are correct too.
I have Oracle 11g installed.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: the steps you went through in SQL/Plus to create, unlock and grant permissions to the new user; how you were connecting to it from SQL/Plus (or from the console); and what connection details you've put into SQL Developer? (Please hide the passwords, we don't need to know it.) If we don't know what you've done/tried then we're going to be guessing at what the problem is.

Comment: Show us your connection properties, your create user command, connecting in sqlplus...